# How did "heavy" shift semantically to mean "stubbornness, defiance, obstinacy"?

Tags: etymology

<sub>Preface: Please pardon me for writing in English; I do not speak German (yet!). This question was motivated by my noticing of the Germanic root **krīg‑* in III.c. during my reading of the PIE root [g<sup>w</sup>erə-<sup>1</sup>](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#gwer%C9%99-1).</sub>

> [[Etymonline:]](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=kriegspiel&allowed_in_frame=0) [...] from Krieg "war,"
>   from Middle High German kriec, "combat," mostly "exertion, effort; opposition, enmity, resistance,"
>   **[2.]** from Old High German *chreg* "stubbornness, defiance, obstinacy,"
>   **[1.]** perhaps from PIE **gwere*- (2) "heavy" (see [grave](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=grave&allowed_in_frame=0) (adj.)) [...]
>
> [The [etymology of Krieg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Krieg#Etymology) quotes [Wiktionary on Proto-Germanic **krīgaz*:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/kr%C4%ABgaz)]
>   Perhaps from *krīganą ‎(“to strive, acquire”), from Proto-Indo-European *gʷréh₂us, *gʷer- ‎(“heavy”).

What underlying semantic notions connect 1 and 2?

Comment: I do not know who voted that this is off-topic, but this question is about Old High German.

Comment: @Carsten S: Not really about Old High German, but I agree this is on topic. It’s just not answerable, except by wild guesses. I’ve therefore voted to close as “primarily opinion-based”.

Comment: @chirlu, I under stand the question as: How do you explain the suggested origin of the Old High German word *chreg* in PIE **gwere-* from a semantic point of view.

Comment: @CarstenS +1. Thanks for your support. Your understanding is correct; please feel free to refine my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I read (or hear) “heavy”, I think of weightfulness rather than difficulty. In German, its cognate *schwer* means both “heavy” and “difficult”.

An adjective, “grave” derives from Latin *[gravis](http://www.albertmartin.de/latein/?q=gravis)* for “heavy”, also meaning “serious”, which itself originated from Proto-Indo-European **swēr-* ([DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=schwer)/[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/sw%C4%93raz)), which is also the etymology of *schwer*. However, *gravis* [seems to have derived](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gravis#Latin) from **gʷréh₂us*, which in turn sounds a bit like **gwere-*.

All of those seem to share some origin, probably owing their semantic similarity. Your question was what semantic link there was. I think in German it would be a bit easier to feel the (linguistic) closeness of war effort, its gloom (German: Schwermut) and the participant’s heavy burden:

> Für das Land ist Krieg üblicherweise eine schwere Last.
>
> To the land, war is usually a heavy burden.

That’s my guess. Also, both “obstinacy” and “stubbornness” may translate to *Hartnäckigkeit* or *Starrsinn*, and I can feel how “heavy” and its various meanings may play a role in its meaning. It’s hard to explain.

Note that this is merely speculation, due to the nature of the question. I’m afraid you won’t find a definitive answer. We will probably never know why **krīganą* ‎(“to strive, acquire”) derived from **gʷréh₂us*, *gʷer-* ‎(“heavy”).